# Remove files with strange name, no inode name, and not shown by ls

Tags: windows, ubuntu, inode, mobaxterm

It all started in windows
, where I found on a USB stick key several files with no name or with strange names, listed as created in 1980 and that could not be removed, as shown below [image: Windows example]. The error messages I got when trying to remove them were either "Permission required" or "The file name is too long".
Ok, I said, I will turn to linux (actually, I just opened the MobaXterm terminal, thinking it would be a 5 seconds job).

I navigated to the incriminated folder, and just typed

```
ls -l
```

to find out that the command returned the names of all the other files in the folder, while fo the files "from the 80s" it listed the following message:

```
"ls: ./0: No such file or directory"
```

The same message was shown for all the files from the 80s. Following the suggestion from some other forum, I tried to get the inode name for the files using

```
ls -li
```

But (as expected) I got the inode number for all the files excepted those "from the 80s", for which I still got the message

```
ls: ./a: No such file or directory
```

Thinking I was smart, I tried to work on the creation date. I found a suggestion on how to remove files created before a given date [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102752/remove-all-files-created-before-a-certain-date).
I created the timestamp file as suggested (with the same date); then, as a check, I just run the find part, without executing the removal part. What I got was the list of a few files older than the timestamp and a series of messages like the one shown below

```
find: ./a: No such file or directory
```

So: what should I try now? I am open to solutions in windows or ubuntu.

Comment: `I will turn to linux (actually, I just opened the MobaXterm terminal, thinking it would be a 5 seconds job)` -- Note: MobaXterm is not Linux.

Comment: If there are files you want to save, do the backup now. These strange names *may* indicate a corruption in the filesystem or the stick itself. Any action that changes its state may make the situation worse.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, you are right. It just provides some very basic Unix commands!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest solution would be to move all files that you want to keep to another folder, and then deleting the folder containing these weird files recursively, without following links.